# Check if same position characters are equal in two strings

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below

[image]

and i want to get the results of table if any of the characters in same position are equal

example:

*fullname*: **ANURADHA KONGARI**
*names*: **AK**

*withoutinitials*: **AI**

here in the example first letter of AK and first letter of AI are equal. so it should return the result.

I have tried using `substring` but it results all the records. Because of the length

example of what i have tried

```
select fullname, names, withoutinitials from #localtable where substring(names,1,1)= substring(withoutinitials,1,1)
or
substring(names,2,1)= substring(withoutinitials,2,1)
or
substring(names,3,1)= substring(withoutinitials,3,1)
```

Here is a way I tried. It is working but what if when the string length is greater 4

```
create table #lt2(fullname varchar(100))
insert into #lt2 select getName=case  
    when len(names)=1 and substring(names,1,1) = substring(withoutinitials,1,1) 
    then fullname 
    when len(names)=2 and ((substring(names,1,1) = substring(withoutinitials,1,1))or(substring(names,2,1) = substring(withoutinitials,2,1))) 
    then fullname 
    when len(names)=3 and ((substring(names,1,1) = substring(withoutinitials,1,1))or(substring(names,2,1) = substring(withoutinitials,2,1)) or (substring(names,2,1) = substring(withoutinitials,2,1))) 
    then fullname 
    when len(names)=4 and ((substring(names,1,1) = substring(withoutinitials,1,1))or(substring(names,2,1) = substring(withoutinitials,2,1)) or (substring(names,2,1) = substring(withoutinitials,2,1))
    or (substring(names,3,1) = substring(withoutinitials,3,1))) 
    then fullname else ''
    end
    from #localtable

select * from #lt2 where fullname!=''
```

But this results all the records because some records may not have length 3 so, it even returns the names with length 1.

I want to get the results if atleast one character of two strings are equal in same position.

> like 1st position of string1 = 1st position of string 2 or 2nd
>   position of string1 = 2nd position of string 2 in a generalized way.

Thank you.

Comment: write a scalar function to check the strings by looping through the legnth of the shorter string and checking each character.  if  a match comes up, return true, but otherwise the loop ends and you return false.

Comment: @Cato I tried to do, but its showing an error `showplan permission` denied

Comment: have you got the SQL of the function that you wrote?

Comment: @Cato sorry, I have deleted it ! but i tried naive approach . I want it to work for strings of any length. Please see the updated question

Comment: your 'showplan permission' sounds like something to do with the permission to see the query execution plan, as opposed to the function being in error

Comment: @Cato yes, is there any other way to write loop inside the select statement

Comment: yes you could use a cursor with loop, then have a nested loop looping around the strings, then add successes to a temp table, then query temp table

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 1 and 2 for your positions, and add an additional check for blank spaces when there are not two characters.

```
declare @table table (fullname varchar(64), names varchar(2), withoutinititals varchar(2))
insert into @table
values
('GANGA RAJAM','GR','AM'),
('ANURADHA KONGARI','AK','AI'),
('PATEL SHIVAJI','R','H'),
('NEW NAME','X','X')

select
    *
    ,substring(names,1,1)
    ,substring(names,2,1)
    ,substring(withoutinititals,1,1)
    ,substring(withoutinititals,2,1)
from @table
where
    (substring(names,1,1) = substring(withoutinititals,1,1))
    or
    (substring(names,2,1) = substring(withoutinititals,2,1) and substring(withoutinititals,2,1) != '')
```

Notice if you remove this part of the where clause, `substring(withoutinititals,2,1) != ''`, you will get false positives

Comment: Thank you, But What if the string lenght i.e, names length is greater than 2? do i need to write the substring again?

Comment: if you are trying to check every single letter against every letter then yes, you need to use a loop ideally a full text index

Comment: Yeah! That is what i want, but i failed to do so and I dont have permissions to create a function :(

Comment: ask John above for some XML magic... it's pretty good at that

Comment: @scsimon Thanks for the chuckle

Comment: can you make a 'temporary function'?   e.g.called #compare

Answer (score 0):

Right pad with unequal  chars `'0'` for `names` and `'1'` for `withoutinitials`:

```
select fullname, names, withoutinitials from #localtable where 
substring(names, 1, 1) = substring(withoutinitials, 1, 1)
or
substring(LEFT(CONCAT(names, '0'), 2), 2, 1) = substring(LEFT(CONCAT(withoutinitials, '1'), 2), 2, 1)
or
substring(LEFT(CONCAT(names, '00'), 3), 3, 1) = substring(LEFT(CONCAT(withoutinitials, '11'), 3), 3, 1)
or
substring(LEFT(CONCAT(names, '000'), 4), 4, 1) = substring(LEFT(CONCAT(withoutinitials, '111'), 4), 4, 1)
```

with sample data:

```
INSERT INTO localtable (fullname, names, withoutinitials) VALUES ('abc1', 'GR', 'AM');
INSERT INTO localtable (fullname, names, withoutinitials) VALUES ('abc2', 'G', 'A');
INSERT INTO localtable (fullname, names, withoutinitials) VALUES ('abc3', 'GR', 'GM');
INSERT INTO localtable (fullname, names, withoutinitials) VALUES ('abc4', 'R', 'R');
INSERT INTO localtable (fullname, names, withoutinitials) VALUES ('abc5', 'GRAA', 'AMAM');
INSERT INTO localtable (fullname, names, withoutinitials) VALUES ('abc6', 'GRS', 'AMS');
INSERT INTO localtable (fullname, names, withoutinitials) VALUES ('abc7', 'AGR', 'AAM');
INSERT INTO localtable (fullname, names, withoutinitials) VALUES ('abc8', 'GR', 'AM');
```

the result is:

```
    fullname    names   withoutinitials
1   abc3        GR      GM
2   abc4        R       R
3   abc5        GRAA    AMAM
4   abc6        GRS     AMS
5   abc7        AGR     AAM
```

Answer (score 0):

just a bit of fun, but I tried a recursive CTE

```
--select distinct top 4000 employeeid, surname, ForeName1 forename into #test from isEmployeeMaster where Sequence  = 1 



;WITH S AS (SELECT 1 AS A, M.employeeid as E, M.Surname as sur, SUBSTRING(M.surname,1,1) ATOM FROM #test M 
            UNION ALL
            SELECT A + 1, E, sur, SUBSTRING(S.sur,A+1,1)  FROM S WHERE A < LEN(S.sur) 
            ),
      F AS (SELECT 1 AS A, M2.employeeid as E, M2.forename as fore, SUBSTRING(M2.forename,1,1) ATOM FROM #test M2
            UNION ALL
            SELECT A + 1, E, fore, SUBSTRING(f.fore,A+1,1)  FROM f WHERE A < LEN(f.fore) 
            )

            select t.* from #test t where t.EmployeeId  in 
            (select s.e  from S join F on S.E = F.E and S.Atom = F.Atom and S.A = F.a)



--drop table #test
```